# How to derive the transformation of a holonomy under a gauge transformation from the defining integral formula of holonomy?

Tags: gauge-theory

I read in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.physletb.2020.135808) "Gauge fields and quantum entanglement" by J. Mielczarek and T. Trześniewski that there are two ways of deriving the transformation of a holonomy of a gauge field under a gauge transformation: one way is from the definition formula of the holonomy as the integral of the associated connection 1-form over a path$-$which treats holonomies as parallel-transported elements of the gauge group; the other way is from treating holonomies as isomorphisms between Hilbert spaces.

I think the latter way is very easy as shown in the following.

---

By treating a holonomy $h$ as a map between the Hilbert space at $s$, $\mathcal{H}_s$, and the Hilbert space at $t$, $\mathcal{H}_t$, of a spatial hypersurface $\Sigma$ of spacetime, we can write $h$ as $$h=h_{IJ}|I \rangle_{st} \langle J|\in \mathcal{H}_s\otimes\mathcal{H}^*_t.$$ Then under a unitary transformation at both $s$, $U_s$, and $t$, $U_t$—which aren't necessarily the same—$|I\rangle^{'}_s=U_{sKI}|K \rangle_{s}, |J\rangle^{'}_t=U_{tLJ}|L \rangle_{t}$, together with $h^{'}_{IJ}|I \rangle^{'}_{st} \langle J|^{'}=h_{KL}|K \rangle_{st} \langle L|$, one can find $U_{sKI}h^{'}_{IJ}U^\dagger_{tJL}=h_{KL}$, which, written in terms of the operator notation, is $U_sh^{'}U^\dagger_t=h$, which is equivalent to $$h'=U^\dagger_shU_t.$$

---

But I feel it's difficult to see how to derive it from the former way.

---

From the perspective of parallel transport of the gauge group, the holonomy of the gauge field $A^i_a$ associated with the connection $1$-form $A=A^i_a\tau_idx^a$ is defined as $$h_e[A]:=\mathcal{P}\exp \int_e A,$$ where $\tau_i$'s are the generators of the Lie algebra of the gauge group, $e$ is a path $e: [0,1]\rightarrow \Sigma$ intervened between $e(0)=s$ and $e(1)=t$ on $\Sigma$, and $\mathcal{P}$ denotes the path ordering. Then  under a unitary transformation, the connection $1$-form transforms as $A^{'}\rightarrow U^\dagger AU+U^\dagger dU$, which leads the holonomy to transform as $$h^{'}_e[A]=U^\dagger(e(0))h_e[A]U(e(1))=U^\dagger_sh_e[A]U_t.$$ I cannot see how the transformation is reached:$$h^{'}_e[A]=\mathcal{P}\exp \int_e (U^\dagger AU+U^\dagger dU)\overset{?}{=}U^\dagger_s\left (\mathcal{P}\exp \int_e A\right)U_t.$$

Comment: 1. This is not a "holonomy" (this is the term when the path is a closed loop), it's just a parallel transport operator (sometimes called *Wilson line* as opposed to *Wilson loop* in the closed case). 2. Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290516/50583 (or at least the answer there should answer this question)

Comment: @ACuriousMind I call it holonomy just by following that paper. But is a holonomy as a integral over a closed path a tensor? If the path is open, it seems not to be a tensor as $h_e[A]\rightarrow U^\dagger_s h_e[A]U_t$ - a tensor should transform as $h_e[A(x)]\rightarrow U^\dagger_x h_e[A(x)]U_x$. But this integral is path-dependent, so I ain't sure if it is a tensor even when the path is closed. I ask this because that paper says "(superpositions of) spin networks themselves can be treated as tensor networks" and "A state of the spin network is constructed as a contraction of the holonomies".

Answer (score 1):

I'd be interested if someone could provide a reference in the literature that takes the time to prove it? But anyway, here we go.

**Background.**
Let's recap some of the stuff stated in the question, just so the answer is relatively self-contained. Let $\{A_{\mu}\}_{\mu=1}^{k}$ be the components of the Berry connection $\mathbf{A}$ on a rank $m$ vector bundle whose

- Base space is $k$-manifold $\mathcal{M}$ (the parameter space, in which anticlockwise loop $C$ is adiabatically spanned; let $C$ be parametrised by smooth map $\lambda:[0,T]\to\mathcal{M}$).
- Fibres are the ($m$-dimensional) ground state of the Hilbert space. Let $\mathcal{H}(\lambda)$ denote the fibres over $C$.

Recall that $A_{\mu}\in\mathfrak{u}(m)$ is a skew-Hermitian linear operator of rank $m$. Let $g:C\to U(\mathcal{H}(\lambda))$ be a smooth map that acts as a change of orthonormal basis on each fibre $\mathcal{H}(\lambda)$, i.e. $g$ is a gauge transformation. The connection transforms as $A_{\mu}\mapsto A_{\mu}'= g^{\dagger}A_{\mu}g - g^{\dagger}\partial_{\mu}g$.

**OP's question (paraphrased).**
Let $\gamma:[0,T]\to\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth path from $a\in\mathcal{M}$ to $b\in\mathcal{M}$ with no self-intersections in the interval $(0,T)$. Let $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma)$ denote the parallel transport along $\gamma$ with respect to connection $\mathbf{A}$. That is, $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma)=\mathcal{P}\left(\exp\int_{a}^{b} A_{\mu}d\lambda^{\mu}\right)$ where we use Einstein summation. How does the parallel transport transform?

**Claim.** Gauge transformations only act on parallel transport along a path $\gamma$ at the endpoints. That is, $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}'}(\gamma)=g^{\dagger}(b)\circ\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma)\circ g(a)$.

**Proof.** It suffices to consider parallel transport along a segment $[\lambda_0,\lambda_0 + \delta\lambda]$. Taking $\delta\lambda\to 0$ and starting with $g(\lambda_0 + \delta\lambda)\circ\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}'}(\gamma)\circ g^{\dagger}(\lambda_0)$,

$g(\lambda_0 + \delta\lambda)\circ\mathcal{P}\left(\exp\int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_0+\delta\lambda} A'_{\mu}d\lambda^{\mu}\right)\circ g^{\dagger}(\lambda)=g_{\lambda_0 + \delta\lambda}\circ\left(\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{H}(\lambda_0)}+\mathbf{A}'(\lambda_0)\cdot\delta\lambda+O(\delta\lambda^2)\right)\circ g^{\dagger}_{\lambda_0}=\ldots$

Using $g_{\lambda_0+\delta\lambda}=g_{\lambda_0}+\partial_{\mu}g|_{\lambda_0}\delta\lambda^{\mu}+O(\delta\lambda^{2})$ and continuing,

$\ldots=\mathbf{1}_{\mathcal{H}(\lambda_0)}+\left(\partial_{\mu}g|_{\lambda_0}\circ g_{\lambda_0}^{\dagger}\right)\delta\lambda^{\mu} + \left(g_{\lambda_0}\circ A_{\mu}'(\lambda_0)\circ g_{\lambda_0}^{\dagger}\right)\cdot\delta\lambda^{\mu}+O(\delta\lambda^2)$

 $\phantom{\ldots}=\mathcal{P}\left( \exp \int_{\lambda_0}^{\lambda_0+\delta\lambda}\left[ (\partial_{\mu}g)g^{\dagger}+gA_{\mu}'g^{\dagger} \right] d\lambda^{\mu} \right)=\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma) \quad \blacksquare$