# What is the effect on Berry’s phase of a non-closed path in configuration space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, berry-pancharatnam-phase

I’m following Professor Zweibach’s [MIT lecture series](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-06-quantum-physics-iii-spring-2018/) $8.06$ on and looking at the section on Berry’s phase for a system undergoing changes in configuration. He explains that in order for the process to be gauge invariant—and hence observable—the system must undergo a closed path in configuration space, which I can understand.

But in practice, a *perfectly* closed path is clearly not possible. How, then, does such a process proceed for a *nearly* closed path? How does the gauge variance manifest as one deviates continuously from such a path?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by 'a perfectly closed path is not possible?' The Berry phase is defined as the phase accumulated by a wavefunction after some adiabatic cyclic evolution of a Hamiltonian parameter. If, say, we use the wavenumber $k$ of the 1D Brillouin zone as this parameter then it is it not possible to create a closed loop (due to the periodicity of the BZ which is just a line in the 1D case)? Apologies if I've misinterpreted your question.

Comment: In any case, I think the answer is just that is the geometric phase you pick up for an open path. Imagine the process of parallel transporting an arrow around a great triangle on a sphere. The geometric phase you acquire (i.e. the angle between the initial and final orientation of your arrow) once you return to your starting point will tell you something about the geometry of your sphere. If, instead of a closed loop, you parallel transport your arrow around an open path on the sphere then you will still acquire a geometric phase.

Comment: An example mentioned is a spin state in a slowly varying magnetic field. Some experimental error (however small) will presumably creep in if you try such an experiment. He derives the geometric phase based on some set of instantaneous eigenstates, then shows that a choice of a different, but equally valid, set of states (based on an arbitrary phase function) gives a different result unless the configuration returns to its initial point. He stresses that this implies the geometric phase is “not observable” unless this is satisfied. I guess I’m wondering what is meant by “not observable” here.

Answer (score 0):

I'll allow for a degenerate ground state in the following. It seems like there's two questions (including the comments thread). Paraphrased,

1. What is meant by "not observable" in the context of parallel transport along a path $\gamma$ with respect to Berry connection $\mathbf{A}$?
2. If the Berry phase is only physically meaningful for loops (closed paths), how can it be observed in real-life systems where it might be impossible to span a perfect loop in the parameter space?

**Answers**

1. Let $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma)$ denote the parallel transport along path $\gamma:[0,T]\to\mathcal{M}$ (from point $a$ to $b$ in the parameter space $\mathcal{M}$) with respect to Berry connection $\mathbf{A}$. Let $g:[0,T]\to\mathcal{M}$ be a smooth family of gauge transformations along $\gamma$. Gauge transformations only act on the parallel transport at the endpoints of $\gamma$. That is, if $\mathbf{A}\mapsto\mathbf{A}'$ under the gauge transformation, then  $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}'}(\gamma)=g^{\dagger}(b)\circ\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma)\circ g(a)$. For more details / background, [see my answer to this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/653696/how-to-derive-the-transformation-of-a-holonomy-under-a-gauge-transformation-from/774789#774789). If the ground state is $m$-fold degenerate, then $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(\gamma), g(t)\in U(m)$. Since $g$ amounts to a mere change of orthonormal basis on the ground state space for each point along $\gamma$, it should not have any physically observable consequences. However, we can see that when $\gamma$ is not closed, the parallel transport can be arbitrarily transformed. On the other hand, if $\gamma$ is a closed loop $C$ (i.e. $a=b$), we see that $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}'}(C)=G^{\dagger}\circ\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(C)\circ G$ where $G:=g(a)$. That is, the "holonomy" (i.e. parallel transport around a loop) has gauge-invariant meaning, since its spectral decomposition is invariant. Specifically, if $\mathcal{H}(t)$ is the ground state over $\gamma(t)$, then the holonomy $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(C)$ acts on $\mathcal{H}(0)$ and has spectral decomposition $\sum_{k} u_{k}\Pi_{k}$ where $u_k \in U(1)$ are eigenvalues of the unitary operator $\Gamma_{\mathbf{A}}(C)$, and $\Pi_{k}$ are orthogonal projectors onto its eigenspaces. Clearly, said eigenspaces are always isomorphic under conjugation by $G$. This is why it is said that the Berry phase is undefined for open paths (*-- with a bit of wiggle room I suppose! See answer 2*), and has physical significance for closed paths.
2. I'll sketch how I think the argument would go. Suppose $\gamma: [0 , T] \to \mathcal{M}$ parametrises a *smooth* loop $C$ in $\mathcal{M}$ with $\gamma(0)=\gamma(T)$. In practice, such a loop might be adiabatically, and imperfectly spanned according to a path of form $\gamma : [0,T'] \to \mathcal{M}$ where $T'=T-\epsilon$. The parallel transport is realised by an operator $\mathcal{P}\left(\exp (h(T-\epsilon))\right)$ where we define $h(\tau):=\int_{0}^{\tau} A_{\mu}\dot{\gamma}^{\mu} dt\in\mathfrak{u}(m)$. Let $\tilde{h}:=h(T-\epsilon)$. First, we Taylor expand $\exp(\tilde{h})$ to get $\Gamma:=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(h(T-\epsilon))^{n}=\mathbf{1}+\tilde{h}+\frac{1}{2!}\tilde{h}^{2}+\frac{1}{3!}\tilde{h}^{3}+\cdots$. Next, we Taylor expand $h(T-\epsilon)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n!}(-\epsilon)^{n}h^{(n)}(T)=h-\epsilon\dot{h}+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon^{2}\ddot{h}+\cdots=h(T)+O(\epsilon)$, which we then plug back into $\Gamma$ to get $\Gamma=\exp (h(T))+O(\epsilon)$. Note that all terms in $O(\epsilon)$ are composed from time-derivatives of $h$; all such terms will be gauge-variant. For instance, $\dot{h}(T)=A_{\mu}(T)\dot{\lambda}^{\mu}(T)$, $\ddot{h}(T)=\dot{A}_{\mu}(T)\dot{\lambda}^{\mu}(T)+A_{\mu}(T)\ddot{\lambda}^{\mu}(T)$ etc. We know that the Berry connection (and consequently its derivatives with respect to $\tau$) are gauge-variant. Consequently, the parallel transport operator along $\gamma$ (from $\tau=0$ to $\tau=T-\epsilon$) is given by $\mathcal{P}(\exp\oint_{\gamma}\mathbf{A}\cdot d\lambda)+O(\epsilon)$. Since the $O(\epsilon)$ correction-terms are gauge-variant, they do not contribute to any physically observable effect of the parallel transport; however, the holonomy $\mathcal{P}(\exp\oint_{\gamma}\mathbf{A}\cdot d\lambda)$ with respect to the closed loop $\gamma$ (i.e. from $\tau=0$ to $\tau=T$) is a gauge-invariant contribution, and hence in principle, is observable. This argument should hold up as long as $\epsilon$ (the accuracy to which the loop is spanned) is sufficiently small that the Taylor expansion of $h(T-\epsilon)$ converges.

**tl;dr:** 1. Gauge-variant of quantity implies that it is merely a mathematical artefact of formulation, thus not physically observable; gauge-invariance of a quantity is necessary for it to be physically observable. Parallel transport along an open path w.r.t Berry connection is gauge-variant, and is gauge-invariant for a closed path. 2. Taylor expand transport along a path which is almost a loop (out by $\epsilon$); correction terms from expansion are of order $\epsilon$ and are all gauge-variant, leaving a gauge-invariant contribution coming from the holonomy.